# the linker doesnt want to recognize the lib file

Tags: c, winapi, codeblocks

I want to create a [queue timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I call `CreateTimerQueueTimer`
but it doesn't compile because it says

> undefined reference to CreateTimerQueueTimer

and I showed the linker the path to the Kernel32.lib.

I use CodeBlocks, right click on project name -> Build Option -> Linker Setting tab -> then clicked Add and went to the lib path, but it didn't help. What causes this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CreateTimerQueueTimer is a more recent API in Win32. To enable it you need to define _WIN32_WINNT as 0x0500 or later. Add to your preproccessor defines _WIN32_WINNT=0x0500.

Comment: Thank you for you help, why it wasnt mentioned at MSDN?